# Can you explain me why?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbial-phrases

I'm studying english now and something confused my mind.
Question;

> "On average, the Japanese car companies are ........ ones in the world market.
>   A) the most productive
>   B) more productive

I thought  it is A because of "in the world market" But true one is B, why?

Comment: To my ear, B is incorrect.  A would be fine.  B should either be "the more productive", or else "ones" should be omitted.  Is this from a textbook?

Comment: Yeah from a textbook

Comment: What text book?  Can you find it on google books?

Comment: Hmm probably I can't find. The book is called "Test Master" It is prepared for Turkish students who study english

Answer (score 0):

Either you have missed some detail of the question or the book is wrong.

Of the two options only a superlative "the most productive" could work here, as there is no obvious other country with which to compare.

Comment: I checked it, I have no mistake so probably the question is wrong